# How to change Hard Drive icons on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, icons

I would like to know how can I change a Hard Drive icon under Windows XP. I know how to change folder icons, but how is it done for a Drive icon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, the way to do it with a removable drive (not sure if this works with, e.g. your hard drive), is to make an `autorun.inf` file in the root of the drive with these contents (e.g. in E:)

```
[autorun]
icon=drive.ico
```

where `drive.ico` is the file name of the icon you want for your drive.  Note that it should probably be on the same drive as the autorun file.  You may wish to hide the icon file - this won't affect the display of the icon in any way.

Answer (score 7):

There is an article [here](http://www.tweakxp.com/article36840.aspx) on how to do this.  Steps below:

To change a drive icon:

1. Click Start | Run | Type regedit and click OK
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SOFTWARE | Microsoft | Windows | CurrentVersion | Explorer
3. Create a new key called DriveIcons
4. Under DriveIcons create a new key with the drive letter (e.g. C)
5. Within this drive letter key create a new key and name DefaultIcon.
6. Give the default value, the icon you want to use e.g. c:\windows\system32/shell32.dll,74

Comment: The change is instant, no need to restart.  Works in Vista/Windows 7 too.