# How to change the Icon in local disk C?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Drive Icon](https://superuser.com/questions/28592/change-drive-icon)

I want to change the icon in local disk C or any other local disk. Because I do not want the usual icon in windows default.

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/28592/change-drive-icon/28597#28597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Tuneup Styler](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tune-up.com%2Fproducts%2Ftuneup-utilities%2Ffeatures%2Fincrease-performance%2F&ei=Bq0aS6bmEYSqngPWh_XjAw&usg=AFQjCNFMdQtcVtynbOXR0MVkgSqs09th6w&sig2=M_QeptX-sO1wKuBs6lDHkQ) to change any of the system icons...

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial works for Windows 7 as well:

**[How to Change a Drive Icon in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/111388-drive-icon-change.html)**